# Cross-referencing summary tables by qwraps2::summary_table()

Tags: r, ms-word, bookdown, cross-reference, qwraps2

I was trying to cross-reference a summary table created using `qwraps2::summary_table()` in my R Markdown Word report, but it did not work with my .Rmd file below.

````
---
title: "Summary table in R Markdown"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)
```

A summary of the group is in Table \@ref(tab:summ-tab):

```{r summ-tab, results="asis"}

library(tidyverse)
library(qwraps2)
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")

tdf <- tibble(
  age = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 40),
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  bmi = runif(n = 30, min = 15, max = 45),
  disease = sample(1:2, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

summary_str <- list(
  "Sex, n (%)" = list(
    "Male" = ~ n_perc0(sex == "M", digits = 1),
    "Female" = ~ n_perc0(sex == "F", digits = 1)
  ),
  "Age, mean &plusmn; SD" = list(
    "Age (yr)" = ~ mean_sd(age, digits = 0)
  ),
  "BMI, mean &plusmn; SD" = list(
    "BMI (kg m^-2^)" = ~ mean_sd(bmi, digits = 1)
  )
)

tdf %>%
  group_by(disease) %>% 
  summary_table(summary_str) %>% 
  print()      
  # knitr::kable(caption = "Personal summary")
  # qable(caption = "Personal summary")

```
````

Screenshot of the .docx file using `print()` as the output method for the `qwraps2_summary_table` object:

[image]

For my other tables created using `knitr::kable()`, `knitr::kable()` would generate a table label for cross-referencing, so I tried to output the table using `knitr::kable()` instead of the `print()` method. The cross-reference worked, but the table itself was not rendered correctly in my .docx file:

[image]

Considering that `qwraps2::qable()` is a wrapper for `knitr::kable()`, I tried it, too, but the cross-reference was broken again, and it only half-rendered the table (missing the group titles):

[image]

I searched online but did not seem to find a solution to my issue, so will really appreciate someone's help.

Comment: Please check the following answer https://www.reddit.com/r/rstats/comments/8w4zkl/summary_table_from_package_qwraps2_does_not_render/

Comment: Thanks, @NaremanDarwish. If you meant the "summary_table from package qwraps2 does not render" question and the solution of adding `results="asis"` to the R code chunk option, I had come across them before - I have the option in my code chunk. My problem is: the `print()` output of the qwraps2_summary_table object rendered the table correctly, but couldn't generate a table label; the `knitr::kable()` generated a label for cross-referencing, but did not render the table; `qwraps2::qable()` being a function in `qwraps2` and a wrapper of `kable()` couldn't marry the two to do the trick, either...

Comment: The issue here results from the way qwraps2 uses the argument `format` and how that argument is passed to knitr::kable.  The bad news is that right now, qwraps2 v 0.4.2 will not support this feature of knitr.  In general I tend to explicitly write labels and captions for tables and figures in my documents and I don't rely on the automated construction from knitr.  I will revisit how qwraps2 passes arguments to `knitr::kable`.  Please refer to the [github issue](https://github.com/dewittpe/qwraps2/issues/84) for development updates.  I will cross post here when appropriate.

Comment: @Peter Thanks very much for your reply! It'll be very useful for me (and other R Markdown beginners like me) to learn from you how you explicitly cross-reference `qwraps2` tables in R Markdown document for Word output. Meanwhile, I will watch the discussion on the GitHub issue page. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Version 0.6.0 of qwraps2 has a fix for this problem.  The addition of the arguments `qable_args` and `kable_args` in the `summary_table` call will allow for the correct passing of arguments from one call to the next, that is, from `summary_table` to `qable` and then to `knitr::kable`.

An example .Rmd file and a screen shot of the resulting .docx file, created by calling `rmarkdown::render` on the .Rmd file, are below:

````
---
title: "Summary table in R Markdown"
output: bookdown::word_document2
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(qwraps2)
options(qwraps2_markup = "markdown")
```

```{r label = "summ_tab_build", include = FALSE}
tdf <- data.frame(
  age = runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 40),
  sex = sample(c("M", "F"), size = 30, replace = TRUE),
  bmi = runif(n = 30, min = 15, max = 45),
  disease = sample(1:2, size = 30, replace = TRUE)
)

summary_str <- list(
  "Sex, n (%)" = list(
    "Male" = ~ n_perc0(sex == "M", digits = 1),
    "Female" = ~ n_perc0(sex == "F", digits = 1)
  ),
  "Age, mean &plusmn; SD" = list(
    "Age (yr)" = ~ mean_sd(age, digits = 0)
  ),
  "BMI, mean &plusmn; SD" = list(
    "BMI (kg m^-2^)" = ~ mean_sd(bmi, digits = 1)
  )
)
```

A summary of the the data by disease group is in Table \@ref(tab:stab) and is
generated via `qwraps2::summary_table`.
More text goes here ...  Table \@ref(tab:stab2) uses `knitr::kable` directly.

```{r label = "stab", echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
summary_table(x = tdf, summaries = summary_str, by = "disease", qable_args = list(kable_args = list(caption = "Personal summary")))
```

More text goes here.

```{r label = 'stab2', echo = FALSE, results = "asis"}
knitr::kable(tdf, caption = "simple table")
```

More text goes here.
````

[image]